# Load script on event and trigger the same event

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, lazy-loading

I am trying to add certain javascript files on an event, say click. I am trying to use the Javascript to be used on same event, only if it is triggered. This is because the scripts are slowing down the page load and there is no need for the scripts otherwise.

Can I just move the scripts to the footer and be all set, or do this pro grammatically via loading them only when needed - via event triggering instead? Below is what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<a id="customId" href="#myLink"></a>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //The async addition
    var myJS = {
      lazyload : function(scriptSrc) {
            if(!this.isPresent(scriptSrc)){
                var scriptTag = document.createElement('script'); 
                scriptTag.src =  scriptSrc;
                scriptTag.async = true; 
                document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scriptTag);
             }
            return false; 
        }
    }; 

    //The event trigger needs to do something using the said script 
    if($('#customId')){
        //Approach 1: 
        var mapEl = document.getElementById("customId"); 
        mapEl.addEventListener("click", customEventHandler, false);
        //mapEl.dispatchEvent(event);
              //*where
              customEventHandler : function(e){
                  e.preventDefault; 
                  myJS.lazyload('/jsfile.js'); 
                // Update or use link relative #href (not complete path) and use the javascript without navigating out of page.
                  //e.currentTarget.dispatchEvent(?); 
            }     

        //2nd attempt: Adds the script, but not able to trigger event to use JS 
        $('#customId').click(function(event) {
          event.preventDefault(); 
          myJS.lazyload('/jsfile.js'); 
        //Either approach: 
        //Trigger the custom event to do an actual click after doing the lazy load, using the JS file
(click);    $('#customId').trigger('click'); //Is this correct on same element ID

      });

   }

}
```

Comment: Would this approach lead to recursive `click` on element?

Comment: I don't want it to be recursive, just do the custom script addition and then navigate to relative link....maybe it is simpler than I am seeing?

Comment: What do you mean by _"and then navigate to relative link."_? What task does loaded `script` perform?

Comment: it loads a map like view using the said jsfile.js script...

Answer (score 1):

Try using `onload` event of `script` element, defining a custom event to prevent recursively calling native `click` event handler on element

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //The async addition
  var myJS = {
    lazyload: function(scriptSrc, id, type) {
      // use `.is()` to check if `script` element has `src` 
      // equal to `scriptSrc`
      if (!$("script[src='"+ scriptSrc  +"']").is("*")) {
        var scriptTag = document.createElement("script");
        scriptTag.src = scriptSrc;
        scriptTag.async = true;
        // use `script` `onload` to trigger custom event `customClick`
        scriptTag.onload = function() {
          $(id).trigger(type)
        };
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(scriptTag);
      }
      return false;
    }
  };

  $("#customId").on("click", function() {
    myJS.lazyload("jsfile.js", "#" + this.id, "customClick");
  })
  // do stuff at `customClick` event
  .one("customClick", function(e) {
    customClick(e.type)
  });

});
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/Rw4BRAfSYlXXe5c6IUml?p=preview

Comment: it seems ok in the plnkr, is there anyway to not do the alert and trying out $(id).trigger(type) if the script is already loaded - i.e else for the if test       if (!$("script[src='"+ scriptSrc  +"']").is("*")) { } else{ $(id).trigger(type) }

Comment: @LoserCoder Yes. The `alert()` call for for example. You would also need substitute `.on()` for `.one()`